# Encrypting a set of integers

Tags: c

I have a problem scenario, where-in, I have to

> 1] get n number of testcases 2] get the input of digits[Can be
>   multiple ints in a single line] e.g: 12 34 123 3] reverse the no's as
>   21 43 321 4] add the reversed numbers 21 + 43 + 321 = 365 5] again
>   reverse the no 365 to 563 6] the output is 563
>
> Above is an example of 1 such test case. if testcase = 3  Input1 => 21
>   22 100  :  O/P => 12 + 22 + 001 = 35 => final op => 53 Input2 => 11
>   100 32  :  O/P => 11 + 001 + 23 = 35 => final op => 53 Input3 => 100
>   21     :  O/P => 001 + 12      = 13 => final op => 31

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>

#define MAX_N 10000
#define MAX_D 5000

int reverse_digits(char* temp){
        int no,rev_no = 0;
        if(temp == NULL) return -1;
        no = atoi(temp);
        printf("\n no : %d \n",no);
        while(no > 0){
                rev_no = ((rev_no * 10)+(no % 10));
                no = no/10;
        }
        return rev_no;

}
int main(){
        int number,prev_no,sum,i;
        char* temp1 = NULL;
        char* test_case = malloc(10);
        char* n = malloc(MAX_D);
        char* op = malloc(MAX_D);
        if(NULL == n || NULL == test_case || NULL == op) return -1;
        number = prev_no = sum = i = 0;
        fgets(test_case,10,stdin);
        for(i = 0; i < atoi(test_case); i++){
                memset(op,0,MAX_D);
                fgets(n,MAX_D,stdin);
                temp1 = strtok(n," ");
                prev_no = reverse_digits(temp1);
                printf("\n prev_no : %d \n",prev_no);
                while(temp1 != NULL){
                        temp1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
                        if(temp1 != NULL){
                                number = reverse_digits(temp1);
                        }
                        sum = prev_no + number;
                        prev_no = sum;
                }
                printf("\n sum : %d \n",sum);
                sprintf(op,"%d",sum);
                printf("\n op : %s` \n",op);
                printf("\n rev: %d \n",reverse_digits(op));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

If I give input as 1 and a single integer as below, I get the answer with a garbage value. Couldnt get why.

op:

```
angus@ubuntu:~/angus/myschool$ ./a.out 
1
12

 no : 12 

 prev_no : 21 

 sum : 21 

 op : 21` 

 no : 21 

 rev: 3254512
```

Bu the answer have to be 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `rev_no` in `reverse digits`.

```
int reverse_digits(char* temp){
        int no,rev_no = 0;
```

Comment: Yeah .. I missed to intialise to 0. Thank

Comment: Also I have added sprintf(op,"%d%c",sum,'/0');

Comment: Is there a way to optimise the above code, such that the execution happens a lot faster